# General website-building: how to keep some paths out of browser history

Tags: cross-browser, browser-history

I have a website where a user may click "log out", and that redirects the user to the path `/logout`. The action is to destroy the user's session cookie and redirect the user back to the login page, with a message that they have successfully logged out.

However, this leads to `$mywebsite/logout` existing in the browser history, and even appearing first in autocomplete results when typing the first few letters of `$mywebsite` in the omnibar.

My question: **How do I specify to the browser to not save a certain path?**

Comment: Use ajax for processing the logout.

Comment: You should use a POST request.

Comment: @SLaks is it best practice to implement this as POST, even in navbars?